# Creating a new Feature Class (ArcCatalog)

Tags: arcgis-9.3, arccatalog

I have ArcGIS 9.3 and when in ArcCatalog, when I R click to create a Feature Class (turn FC), it is greyed out.  Do you need a particular license or ArcEditor/Info to have it?

I went into the toolbox, and when I click the Turn Feature Class in the toolbox, it says i don't have the proper extension/license for it.

A little help here, please.

Thanks,
Zoran

Comment: Are you trying to create a Feature Class in an ArcSDE GeoDatabase?

Comment: Do you have the Network analyst Extension?

Comment: No and No 
Not within a GDB and no on the Network Analyst Ext.

Comment: You can't create a Feature Class outside of a GDB.  The Turn Feature Class that you are trying to create is a feature that requires Network Analyst. First create GDB, then create your feature class inside the GDB.

Comment: I would check the ESRI help files, since turn feature classes are associated with network analysis and would require access to the Network Analyst Extension as a minimum (and perhaps there are other access points for other ESRI software platforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are really trying to create a "normal" featureclass, not a "Turn Feature Class" (that is associated with the Network Analyst extension).

1. Create a geodatabase in ArcCatalog
2. Right-click in the contents view and choose new->[Feature Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/as_a_stand_alone_feature_class/002200000005000000/)

Alternatively, if you want to do it through ArcToolbox, choose ArcToolbox->Data Management Tools->Feature Class->[Create Feature Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002p000000).

Comment: Ryan - perfect, went into GDB and created a Feature Class 

Thank You, Z